# How to produce self-closing tags with AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

For this specific example I'm processing `input` tags doing some work and replacing them with custom tags.
The output is `<customTag>..</customTag>`

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var html = parser.parse(htmlSnippet);
var inputs= originalHtml.QuerySelectorAll("input");
foreach (var element in inputs)
{
  var newElement = html.CreateElement("customTag");
  // do some work.
  element.Replace(newElement);
}

return html.Body.InnerHtml();
```

Is it possible to "produce" self-closing tags with AngleSharp ?

```
<customTag attr="x" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage :

```
var document = new HtmlParser().Parse("");

var tag = document.CreateElement("customTag");
tag.SetAttribute("attr", "x");
tag.AsSelfClosing();

Console.WriteLine(tag.OuterHtml);
tag.ToHtml(Console.Out, CustomHtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance);
```

Output :

```
<customtag attr="x">
<customtag attr="x" />
```

---

Looking at the source, you will find that there 2 places where you can work some stuff in to achieve such thing.

1. `readonly NodeFlags Node._flags` : Keep in mind that this field, its property and the host class are all not exposed. So you would need to some dirty hack to get the job one. Also, the default formatter `HtmlMarkupFormatter` use only `>`, and not `/>`.
2. Create your own `IMarkupFormatter`.

---

Here is a solution that uses both mentioned points.

```
public static class ElementExtensions
{
    public static void AsSelfClosing(this IElement element)
    {
        const int SelfClosing = 0x1;

        var type = typeof(IElement).Assembly.GetType("AngleSharp.Dom.Node");
        var field = type.GetField("_flags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var flags = (uint)field.GetValue(element);
        flags |= SelfClosing;
        field.SetValue(element, Enum.ToObject(field.FieldType, flags));
    }
}

public class CustomHtmlMarkupFormatter : IMarkupFormatter
{
    public static readonly CustomHtmlMarkupFormatter Instance = new CustomHtmlMarkupFormatter();

    public string Text(String text) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.Text(text);
    public string Comment(IComment comment) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.Comment(comment);
    public string Processing(IProcessingInstruction processing) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.Processing(processing);
    public string Doctype(IDocumentType doctype) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.Doctype(doctype);
    //public string OpenTag(IElement element, Boolean selfClosing) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.OpenTag(element, selfClosing);
    public string CloseTag(IElement element, Boolean selfClosing) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.CloseTag(element, selfClosing);
    public string Attribute(IAttr attribute) => HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance.Attribute(attribute);

    public string OpenTag(IElement element, Boolean selfClosing)
    {
        var temp = new StringBuilder();
        temp.Append('<');

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Prefix))
        {
            temp.Append(element.Prefix).Append(':');
        }

        temp.Append(element.LocalName);

        foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes)
        {
            temp.Append(" ").Append(Instance.Attribute(attribute));
        }

        temp.Append(selfClosing ? " />" : ">");

        return temp.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can also remove `ElementExtensions` and add your own logic for when to self-close an element in `CustomHtmlMarkupFormatter.OpenTag`.